# My Windows Azure site is all the sudden incredibly slow?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, azure, hosting

Basically I've been hosting a website on Windows Azure for a couple of months now.
Previously everything has been running smoothly. However all the sudden my site is loading INCREDIBLY slow (we're talking 20s load time). I have no idea what happend - I was running shared mode and before this point everything was running fine.
Below are my stats for the last 7 days (I don't know what else to upload):
[image]

I tried getting support but apparently my plan does not provide technical support.
I decided to upgrade to standard hosting but it's been 30 minutes now and my site is still running just as slow.

Also when I debug it locally everything runs just fine. Furthermore my I'm not connecting to any databases so what could the issue be????

Sometimes the site doesn't even load at all and displays errors such as:

500 - Internal server error

502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.

What could be the problem - what am I supposed to do? Apparently Microsoft provide absolutely NO support so I guess I'm simply forced to switch to another hosting provider if I cannot figure out the issue myself?

Comment: You have enabled stack trace?

Comment: @UsmanKhalid
I'm sorry but how do I enable that?

Comment: Looking at the chart, the app doesn't appear CPU bound (you mentioned auto-scaling by CPU in a comment to an answer). Have you tried simply scaling to two instances? Also: Do you have any shared resource or external service that the site may be blocking on? Are you seeing any type of DOS attack via very high request rates coming in?

Comment: Wanted to just point out that in the free and shared tier, daily CPU usage is capped (60 minutes / day for free, 240 minutes / day for shared). Have you double-checked to make sure your site's now running in Standard mode (Standard mode has no such CPU cap)?

Comment: @JamieRomeo, I am seeing this intermittently as well. Were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: I was able to temporarily resolve this issue by re-deploying my website to azure... definitely not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

have you found something that has increased load(on lines of user hits,transactions) on your sites? since you are running shared mode, you are sharing resources with multiple sites on the same server which could be the reason.
It might be an indication for you to go to dedicated mode.

Comment: My number of visitors has grown recently (receiving several thousands every day) so when this issue occurred I upgraded to standard mode. However it has not helped at all.

Comment: Have you tried changing instance size for your sites?

Comment: No but my scale settings are "scale by metric - CPU" so it should automatically adjust these as far as I'm concerned.
I've updated my original question with some error codes I'm receiving.